# Mac Security - Which one?

Tags: macos, mac, security, anti-virus

Recently I had my credit card cloned. A few hours after shopping at an online store (in which I trust and buy since 2006) I received a call from my bank asking if I recognize a $5,000 debt to a store(?!) called Church of Christ...

I'm a Mac user (OS X 10.6.3). I always kept my system updated and I have firewall enabled (in my Mac and in my broadband router), but I decided to adopt some kind of protection.

I don't want to rise passionate discussions. Real or not, snake oil or not, I need to have back my peace of mind...

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/14450/is-anti-virus-software-needed-for-a-mac-os-x-if-so-free-solution) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/29057/mac-security-software-closed) posts. I selected two software that I think that could help me (both have more features other than just an antivirus). Does someone have feedback about [Intego's VirusBarrier X6](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/virusbarrierx6.html) or [Trendmicro's Smart Surfing](http://us.trendmicro.com/us/products/personal/smartsurfing-mac/)? Intego solutions seems to be better, but TrendMicro brand/name is stronger in corporate environment, so their solution should be good.

Both solutions have 30 day free trial, but I would like to hear something from you. Any other solution that I should look?

TIA,

Bob

Comment: See this post http://superuser.com/questions/139063/choosing-a-good-antivirus-for-mac-os-x/
I currently use Kaspersky, it's really cool.

Comment: @CharlesB. Thanks, I'll give it a try. Despite the antivirus functions (that Kaspersky is well known), I'm looking for solutions that are strong also in internet/network protection.

Comment: You could try Mcafee Internet security (for mac)... but I think it's in beta.

Comment: How do you know your problem was virus related and not a potential problem with an e-commerce site you've used recently?

Comment: You should investigate into that site, it seems like a known way to scam a user. I agree with Darren Newton's comment above. Using a new firewall isn't going to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No surfing protection measure will help you if a trusted online store is suddenly compromised and it's payment system hacked.

In terms of virus protection, I've always been a sceptic when it comes to their use on the Mac. However I've always been impressed with Sophos and they've just bought out a free virus scanner for Mac. I've tried it and it is lightweight and non-intrusive.

Worth a look: http://www.sophos.com/products/free-tools/free-mac-anti-virus/