# Does Mac OS X need an antivirus

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Anti Virus Software needed for a Mac (OS X); If so free solution?](https://superuser.com/questions/14450/is-anti-virus-software-needed-for-a-mac-os-x-if-so-free-solution)

Should people running OS X get antivirus software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you are fine without it if you keep your software up to date (especially Adobe Reader & Flash...) and don't open suspicious files (email attachments, illegally downloaded software).

There are only a few malwares for OS X. Think before you click and you'll be fine... for now!

P.S.: It's a good idea to read IT-News sites like slashdot or heise security to be informed about current malware. That way you know which software poses a threat to your system.

Answer (score 3):

No antivirus is like not wearing a helmet when riding a bike : If you are careful then nothing happens. But the smallest mistake can cause you big troubles.

The Internet is a dangerous place. There are hackers out there trying to take control of your computer, and they are much cleverer and more knowledgeable than you. The hackers are of course always ahead of the antivirus, at least for a while, but the antivirus does protect against known viruses.

The better antivirus products contain databases of known viruses. These databases are growing at the rate of **thousands of new viruses per day**! There are large and well-founded Mafia-type organizations behind these viruses. Do you know that bank-fraud brings in more money than heroine traffic? And do you know that virus-writing is not a crime in Russia?

OS X is less-targeted than Windows, for obvious reasons. But for the same reason OS X computers are often unprotected because of a false feeling of security. Because OS X viruses do exist.

Conclusion: You need an antivirus, I need an antivirus, we all need an antivirus. At least if we connect to the Internet.

Comment: To masked under-voter: This only shows your ignorance.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but I actually *considered* a downvote as I already found a duplicate before you posted, and I feel that answering duplicates is not helping Super User. (But then I guessed you might already have been composing this before I voted to close.)

Comment: @Arjan: Sorry, so I added my vote to close. But I always warn people against mistakenly feeling safe.

Comment: And that warning indeed does not deserve a downvote. Sorry I cannot remove it, but I can compensate it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Better to be SAFE than to be SORRY**

As quoted in  [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10331147-263.html)

> With dubious **reports of a nascent
>   malware menace threatening Mac OS X**'s
>   current status as (for all intents and
>   purposes) a virus-free platform.

**Note**:: ***Just Because there aren't many virus in OS X , it doesn't mean it is not prone to an attack***

Comment: @Sathya Thanks again mate (for editing). You are my hero :)

Answer (score 1):

It's like wearing a helmet in a car. Might add extra protection but is it really worth it?

Just don't download things you don't trust and you'll be fine. Software can always be malicious no matter what protection you add.